# NSTextField, Is it difficult to add? I think

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.2, nstextfield

I've made small game in Xcode 4.2.

After I played all game level, the high-score-input window will appear. I want to add NSTextField to here, so the player could type his name by keyboard.

I added `NSTextField` to OpenGlView, but I can't see it on the screen. What's the matter with this? I also try to add subview and add `NSTextField`, but I get the same result.

Xcode4.2, simulator is My Mac - 32bit.

```
    NSView *view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSRectFromCGRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320))];

    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:view];

    [[view layer] setZPosition:1];
//        
    NSTextField *textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSRectFromCGRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40))];
    [view addSubview:textField];
```

Comment: Maybe its the zPosition issue. Have you tried to set it as the subclass of `window`?

Comment: Inappropriate TITLE for question you asked.

Comment: You'll be more likely to get good answers by improving your question than by adding a bounty.

Comment: NSView *view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSRectFromCGRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320))];

        
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:view];

        
        [[view layer] setZPosition:1];

        NSTextField *textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSRectFromCGRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40))];

        [view addSubview:textField];


This is my code. Please see and help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the documentation for [`NSOpenGLView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenGLView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000465-261) states, it does not support subviews:

> "An `NSOpenGLView` object cannot have subviews. You can, however, divide
>   a single `NSOpenGLView` into multiple rendering areas using the
>   `glViewport` function."

While I'm not sure whether you're using your own `NSOpenGLView` subclass, or whether cocos2d provides a view itself, but it will likely have the same "limitations".

The `NSTextField` could be in the same window, provided it's located such that it doesn't overlap the OpenGL view.

Otherwise, you could just implement that part of the UI in a separate `NSWindow`.

This sample project displays the dialog as a sheet, attached to the main window with the OpenGL view:

[image]

Project: [OpenGLHighScore.zip](http://www.markdouma.com/developer/OpenGLHighScore.zip)